Is sublease income considered passive income and subject to tax reporting?
I am an F-1 student who subleased my apartment last summer while on OPT. I have read that F-1 students are allowed to receive limited passive income, but I am unsure whether income from subleasing is considered passive income, similar to rental income.
A lawyer I consulted mentioned that F-1 students are not allowed to receive any income, and subleasing at a higher rate than my original rent could potentially violate this rule. This has left me with several questions:

Is sublease income considered passive income for F-1 students? Does it require tax reporting?
What factors determine whether income is considered active or passive? Is it based on the nature of the income or the amount?
Does subleasing at a higher rate than my original rent disqualify the income from being considered passive?


I was told that F-1 students cannot receive any income - I don't believe that to be true.

I'm fairly certain that active income refer to wages, so income that isn't from wages (i.e. you selling your time for money) is passive. For the non-wage income, you actually have to profit for it to be income, which is what your lawyer is referring to; (revenue-cost) has to be positive, which in this case meaning the amount you're are charging for the sublease is greater than what your landlord is charging you rent for the lease. I don't know anything specific about F-1 students but generally, all income has to be reported, but you aren't liable for taxes until a specific amount.

@uberhaxed Thanks for the clarification. I’m sharing my apartment with a roommate, so technically the amount I’m charging for the sublease is less than what my landlord is charging me, but more than the portion I’m paying for. While my initial goal wasn’t to profit from subleasing when renting from the landlord, I do end up with a positive profit (revenue - cost). I’m wondering if this non-wage income from subleasing is still considered as passive income or active income. If this income needs to be reported, would I be able to deduct the rent I paid from the amount I receive from the sublease?

When filing taxes, you deduct all costs (e.g. What you pay to the bank if you were leasing instead of sub-leasing) from your revenue, and that's what you report. The only exception is when the costs are from illegal activity; e.g. if your business is selling drugs then you can't deduct the cost of them when reporting income.
